# how to setup the value for com.apple.developer.associated-domains in MyApp.entitlements?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

When I try to upload my app (made with delphi Rio) to the appStore I have this error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key
>   'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/myapp.app/myapp'
>   is not supported."

then I look in the myApp.entitlements that Delphi generate and I have:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<string>*</string>
```

But the problem I don't see where I can change this value? it's seam it's the "*" who make a problem, but don't see where I can change it

Comment: My iOS apps don't have that generated at all. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DaveNottage that very strange you are right nohere in my project I have any mention of com.apple.developer.associated-domains ! I don't yet understand how delphi decide in my project to add it (only in my project)

Comment: @DaveNottage : it's this value that is populated with com.apple.developer.associated-domains: <%keychainAccessGroups%> in Entitlement.TemplateiOS.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original answer:

It looks like the "Associated Domains" option has been selected in your App ID (i.e. on the Apple Developer site), yet Apple are rejecting your app because of it - weird. If it were unsupported, you'd think they'd disable the option.

You'll need to edit the App ID to deselect the option, regenerate your provisioning profile, rebuild and resubmit your app.

Before you do that, you might want to check the other options in the App ID in case any others are rejected. You should really only select those that you need for your app.

**EDIT:**

The answer above is not quite correct - it's the "*" value that the App Store is complaining about. As per this link:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains?language=objc

Domains must be added individually, as you've now discovered. Obviously, Delphi does not offer this capability at present, but should

Comment: Thanks Dave!! the problem is that I need the Associated Domains to handle universal link :( But i don't see where in delphi i can configure the value of com.apple.developer.associated-domains

Comment: Very good point. It appears you may have to do it by having your own copy of the entitlements file, and modify it manually. This link may help: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios/. You could do it in Xcode in a test app and see what the resulting entitlements looks like

Comment: If you're able to work it out, please let me know, and I'll file a report in QP

Comment: I can do a custom entitlements file, and yes then it's work. THE PROBLEM is that the entitlements file need the value get-task-allow to false for appstore (ie launch debugger) and to true for debug and we can not set in delphi a path for entitlements for the debug and a different path for the release :(